# Using DominatorTreeWrapperPass in CallGraphSCCPass

Tags: c++, llvm

I’m writing a `CallGraphSCCPass` which needs dominator tree information on each function. My `getAnalysisUsage` is fairly straightforward:

```
virtual void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage& au) const override
{
    au.setPreservesAll();
    au.addRequired<DominatorTreeWrapperPass>();
}
```

The pass is registered like this:

```
char MyPass::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<MyPass> tmp("My Pass", "Do fancy analysis", true, true);

INITIALIZE_PASS_BEGIN(MyPass, "My Pass", "Do fancy analysis", true, true)
INITIALIZE_PASS_DEPENDENCY(DominatorTreeWrapperPass)
INITIALIZE_PASS_END(MyPass, "My Pass", "Do fancy analysis", true, true)
```

When I try to add my pass to a `legacy::PassManager`, it dies with this error message:

> Unable to schedule 'Dominator Tree Construction' required by ‘My Pass'
>   Unable to schedule pass
>   UNREACHABLE executed at LegacyPassManager.cpp:1264!

I statically link LLVM to my program, and define the pass in my program, too.

Am I doing something wrong? Does it make sense to require the `DominatorTreeWrapperPass` from a `CallGraphSCCPass`?

I also sent the question on the LLVM ML, but the server appears to be down at the moment.

If it makes any difference, I'm using LLVM 3.7 trunk, up-to-date as of a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CallGraphSCCPass appears to be a special case that doesn't support every analysis very well. The simplest thing to do is to convert the pass to a `ModulePass`, and use `<llvm/ADT/SCCIterator.h>` to construct call graph SCCs from `runOnModule`, like how `CGPassManager` does it.

```
virtual void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage& au) const override
{
    au.addRequired<CallGraphWrapperPass>();
    // rest of your analysis usage here...
}

virtual bool runOnModule(Module& m) override
{
    CallGraph& cg = getAnalysis<CallGraphWrapperPass>().getCallGraph();

    scc_iterator<CallGraph*> cgSccIter = scc_begin(&cg);
    CallGraphSCC curSCC(&cgSccIter);
    while (!cgSccIter.isAtEnd())
    {
        const vector<CallGraphNode*>& nodeVec = *cgSccIter;
        curSCC.initialize(nodeVec.data(), nodeVec.data() + nodeVec.size());
        runOnSCC(curSCC);
        ++cgSccIter;
    }

    return false;
}

bool runOnSCC(CallGraphSCC& scc)
{
    // your stuff here
}
```

Module passes take no issue at requiring `DominatorTreeWrapperPass`, or other analyses like `MemoryDependenceAnalysis`. However, this naive implementation might not support modifications to the call graph like `CGPassManager` does.

Answer (score -1):

**CallGraphSCCPass** is a **ModulePass** and hence is being handled and invoked by ModulePassManager, ModulePassManager invokes **FunctionPassManager** (which manages FunctionPasses) and gives the handle to it after invoking Module passes(in the other word ModulePasses queue before FunctionPasses in the PassManager's pipeline), so you can not ask PassManager for a functionPass while you are inside a ModulePass but you can ask for a ModulePass inside FunctionPass since they already have run. by the same reason you can not ask for a LoopPass inside a FunctionPass

Comment: This appears to be contradicting advice from the mailing list suggesting that module passes can access function-specific analyses using the `getAnalysis<T>(Function&)` method. In addition, `CallGraphSCCPass` does not inherit from `ModulePass`.